# Help me writing Payoff matrix.

Tags: self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

[image]

I guess, in order to answer this question, I need to write Payoff matrix. But I cannot write it. And then, I Will able to answer this question by myself. Thank you for helping.

(These are just studying-exercise questions. I Try to learn this topic by the help of the questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payoff matrix is huge in this game since there are so many possible strategies (all the different ways to distribute the $120$ soldiers to the six battlefields).

You just need to check the given configuration of armies. Is the response of $B$ to the $A$'s configuration a best response and vice versa. If so, this is an equilibrium.

EDIT: OK from the formulation of the question I understand that a tie means losing.

---

RE_EDIT: Sorry I didn't think this through. Of course $A$ can change distribution to for example: $(0,38, 22, 22, 21, 17)$ to have a win. So this isn't an equilibrium.

---

Sorry editing all the time but now I think I got it:

The equlibria are those where all the soldiers are divided equally to $3$ battlefields (then the other general cannot win the war and this always forces a tie). So the equlibria are (for example): $A$ plays $(40, 40, 40, 0, 0, 0)$ and it doesn't matter what $B$ plays. Of course you can change the places where the $40$'s are.

Also the ones where $B$ plays the $40$-strategy and it doesn't matter what $A$ plays are equlibria.

Hope I got this right now... :D.

Comment: Sorry I cannot find:(

Comment: My instructor's exercise questions from different books. I just ask the questions I dont understand. I think similarly to you. But I cannot say it since my thought may be false.

Comment: Sorry, totally missthought at first. I hope it is correct now. I think it is since you cannot have over three wins if other has $40$ in three places.

Comment: Okay I understand well right now. Thank you so much:)) I just have learn game theory. This is considirably complicated. But I understand your answers thanks a lot:)

Comment: Ok. I'm no expert myself and it's quite some time ago that I learned the little that I know. But glad if I can help.

Comment: No problem. I can give it a try :D